# Flux store not running function before constructor

Tags: ajax, reactjs, store, flux

I have created a store that attempts to do an AJAX request and set `this.restaurants` to the returned data. If I hard code the data in as an array of json to the `this.restaurants everything works great. But my AJAX call is not being run in time. How can i fix this? The console log displays everything as expected

```
class RestaurantStore extends EventEmitter {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.restaurants = this.getRestaurants()
    }

    getRestaurants() {
        const url =  `/lib/data/restaurants.json`

        var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
        r.open("GET", url, true);
        r.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return;

            const json = r.responseText
            console.log(json)
            return json
            // this.restaurants = json
        };
        r.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: getRestaurants is an asynchronous function. The `this.restaurants = ` is a synchronous assignment. `this.restaurants = this.getRestaurants()` isn't going to wait for the return value of your AJAX; it is showing as undefined, right? You may want to assign `this.restaurants` in a callback after your AJAX has returned. Or any number of competing options (promises, async/await if you have an ES7 environment, etc.)

Comment: Would you be able to give an example? been struggling with this for a while

Comment: Well, for starters you could assign the restaurant property inside your onreadystatechange. It looks like you've tried that at some point, and maybe ran into issues because you don't know when accessing the property whether the request has completed yet. I'm on mobile right now so can't type up anything too involved, but for some starter tips: side-effect heavy functions such as ajax calls should be done in the componentDidMount life cycle function; xhr is easier to manage with a dedicated library (or the new 'fetch'). In Flux in general you should be storing all state in your stores as well.